# The pen/pencil tool is not aligning with my tablet and tablet pen in 2.91.0 2D Animation

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d

I'm very new to Blender so I'll do my best to explain my problem.

When I draw on my Wacom Cintiq 16 tablet the drawing tool doesn't seem to be completely calibrated to my tablet pen. My tablet is connected to my HP Pavilion laptop. I'm seeing two different cursors when the tablet pen is hovering.

When the tablet pen makes contact I only see one of the cursors. But it's not where the pen is drawing. It's off by a millimeter or two.

I've already tried calibrating my tablet pen to the tablet. And that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Anyone able to help me out?[image]